# Put modified xml back into the message?

Tags: cxf, interceptor

I'm using CXF to send messages with SOAP over JMS.

I'm trying to write a CXF Interceptor in the POST_MARSHALL phase.
I want to change some attributes when the xml is generated.

I know i can get the content from the message via

```
message.getContent(java.io.Writer.class).
```

This happens to be in the form of **JMSConduit$1**. Which - I think - is a **StringWriter** (if I debug my code I can see a *buf* field).

I can get the xml in String format and make my changes, but the problems is putting it back in the message.

I can not change the JMSConduit$1 to something else, otherwise CXF won't send it to the JMS Endpoint. (it must be a JMSConduit).

I can't find a way to put the modified xml back in a JMSConduit, which i can get through

```
message.getExchange().getConduit();
```

So, how can I put my modified xml back into the message/JMSConduit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. I used a FilterWriter.

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    final Writer writer = message.getContent(Writer.class);
    message.setContent(Writer.class, new OutWriter(message, writer));
}

class OutWriter extends FilterWriter {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Modify String (in xml form).
        message.setContent(Writer.class, out);
    }
}
```